# cycle for doesn't work as I think multiplication two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a problem with the cycle for in the function realizar_operacion_arreglos. I did the mechanical cycles but the compiler doesn't throw the same thing. I need help for resolve this.

The array `a` is

```
2 3  1
5 -1 7
```

The array `b` is

```
 2  5 2 
 3  0 4
-1  1 1
```

The correct result is

```
12 11 17
 0 32 13
```

but this is the actual result of the code

```
12  11  17
-7  7  7
```

What's wrong?

```
/********************************************************************************
 * Programa 8: Multiplicacion entre 2 arreglos de 2D. Se debe comprobar si primero
 * se puede realizar la multiplicacion. Si se puede retorne 1 si no 0
 *
 * Input: 2 arreglos de 2D, tamaño de cada arreglo
 *
 * Output: multiplicacion de los dos arreglos, condicional si se puede o no la
 *
 * multiplicacion con 0 y 1
 *
  *********************************************************************************/
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

 // Prototipos

 int pedir_fila1();
 int pedir_columna1();
 void **pedir_valores_arreglo1(int **arreglo1, int fila1, int columna1);
 int pedir_fila2();
 int pedir_columna2();
 void **pedir_valores_arreglo2(int **arreglo2, int fila2, int columna2);
 int verificar_multiplicacion(int columna1, int fila2);
 int **realizar_operacion_arreglos(int **arreglo1, int fila1, int columna1, 
 int **arreglo2, int fila2, int columna2);

 // Main

 int main (){
 int fila1, fila2, columna1, columna2, verificacion, i, j = 0;
 int **arreglo1, **arreglo2, **m;
 fila1 = pedir_fila1();
 columna1 = pedir_columna1();
 fila2 = pedir_fila2();
 columna2 = pedir_columna2();
 verificacion = verificar_multiplicacion(columna1,fila2);
 if(columna1==fila2){
 arreglo1 = (int **) calloc(fila1,sizeof(int *));
 for(i = 0; i<fila1; i++){
 arreglo1[i] = (int *) calloc(columna1,sizeof(int));
 }
 arreglo2 = (int **) calloc(fila2,sizeof(int *));
 for(i = 0; i<fila2; i++){
 arreglo2[i] = (int *) calloc(columna2,sizeof(int));
 }
 m = (int **) calloc(fila1,sizeof(int *));
  for(i = 0; i<fila1; i++){
    m[i] = (int *) calloc(columna2,sizeof(int));
 }
 pedir_valores_arreglo1(arreglo1,fila1,columna1);
 pedir_valores_arreglo2(arreglo2,fila2,columna2);
 m=realizar_operacion_arreglos(arreglo1,fila1,columna1,arreglo2,fila2,columna2);

 for(i=0; i<fila1; i++){
 for(j=0; j<columna2; j++){
 printf(" %d ",m[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }printf("\n");
 }else{
 return 0;
 }
 }

 // Desarrollo de los prototipos

 int pedir_fila1(){
 int fila1 = 0;
 printf("Favor ingrese el numero de filas para el arreglo 1 \n");
 scanf("%d",&fila1);
 if(fila1<0){
 printf("No se puede dimensionar la fila negativa");
 return 0;
 }else{
 return fila1;
 }
 }

 int pedir_columna1(){
 int columna1 = 0;
 printf("Favor ingrese el numero de columnas para el arreglo 1 \n");
 scanf("%d",&columna1);
 if(columna1<0){
 printf("No se puede dimensionar la columna negativa");
 return 0;
 }else{
 return columna1;
 }
 }

 void **pedir_valores_arreglo1(int **arreglo1, int fila1, int columna1){
 int i, j = 0;
 for(i=0; i<fila1; i++){
 for(j=0; j<columna1; j++){
 printf("Para el arreglo 1, ingrese la fila %d y la columna %d\n",i+1,j+1);
 scanf(" %d",&arreglo1[i][j]);
 }
 }
 for(i=0; i<fila1; i++){
 for(j=0; j<columna1; j++){
 printf(" %d ",arreglo1[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
 printf("\n");
 }

 int pedir_fila2(){
 int fila2 = 0;
 printf("Favor ingrese el numero de filas para el arreglo 2 \n");
 scanf("%d",&fila2);
 if(fila2<0){
 printf("No se puede dimensionar la fila negativa");
 return 0;
 }else{
 return fila2;
 }
 }

 int pedir_columna2(){
 int columna2 = 0;
 printf("Favor ingrese el numero de columnas para el arreglo 2 \n");
 scanf("%d",&columna2);
 if(columna2<0){
 printf("No se puede dimensionar la columna negativa");
 return 0;
 }else{
 return columna2;
 }
 }

 void **pedir_valores_arreglo2(int **arreglo2, int fila2, int columna2){
 int i, j = 0;
 for(i=0; i<fila2; i++){
 for(j=0; j<columna2; j++){
 printf("Para el arreglo 2, ingrese la fila %d y la columna %d\n",i+1,j+1);
 scanf("%d",&arreglo2[i][j]);
 }
 }
 for(i=0; i<fila2; i++){
 for(j=0; j<columna2; j++){
 printf(" %d ",arreglo2[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
 printf("\n");
 }

 int verificar_multiplicacion(int columna1, int fila2){
 int verificacion = 0;
 if(columna1==fila2){
 printf("La multiplicacion de matrices se puede realizar\n");
 verificacion = 1;
 return verificacion;
 }else{
 printf("La multiplicacion de matrices no se puede realizar\n");
 verificacion = 0;
 return verificacion;
 }
 }

 int **realizar_operacion_arreglos(int **arreglo1, int fila1, int columna1, int **arreglo2, int fila2, int columna2){

 int i, j, k = 0;
 int **resultado;
 resultado = (int **)calloc(fila1,sizeof(int *));
 for(i=0; i<columna2; i++){
 resultado[i]=(int *)calloc(columna2,sizeof(int));
 }

 for ( k = 0; k < fila1; k++){
   int temporal = 0;
   for ( j = 0; j < columna2; j++){
     int temporal = 0;
     for ( i = 0; i < columna1; i++ ){
       temporal += (arreglo1[k][i])*(arreglo2[i][j]);
       resultado[k][j]=temporal;
     }
   }
 }
 return resultado;
 }
```

Comment: someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

In the `int** realizar_operacion_arreglos(...)` function, the variable `int** resultado` is not initialized. It is a pointer, which means that by using it you are writing the result of multiplication into some random area in computer memory. And part of that area is rewritten later, which is precisely the reason why the result is partially correct and partially incorrect.

Therefore, you need to allocate memory for your `resultado` matrix. Replace the line

```
int** resultado;
```

with:

```
int** resultado = (int**)calloc(fila1, sizeof(int*));
for (size_t i = 0; i < fila1; ++i) {
    resultado[i] = (int*)calloc(columna2, sizeof(int));
}
```

(which is really just the same as you already have in the `main()` function for the first two matrices).

Also remember that you should properly `free()` all the memory before your program exits, but first I recommend to concentrate at getting the code working.

### Update 1

You added my code snippet to your program, but at the wrong place. Now, you allocate the right amount of memory, but too soon. After

```
m=realizar_operacion_arreglos(arreglo1,fila1,columna1,arreglo2,fila2,columna2);
```

the pointer `m` is assigned a new value (the incorrect one, as I wrote above) and the memory for the result matrix is lost.

You need to move this allocating code to the `realizar_operacion_arreglos`function. Just remove the

```
int** resultado;
```

line and place

```
int** resultado = (int**)calloc(fila1, sizeof(int*));
for (size_t i = 0; i < fila1; ++fila1) {
    resultado[i] = (int*)calloc(columna2, sizeof(int));
}
```

there instead.

### Update 2

Sorry, there was a typo in the for cycle, which caused infinite loop and Out of Memory condition. It is fixed now.

It seems that with this fix, your program works. At least I get the correct result.

### Update 3

When compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o main main.c`, these warning were emitted:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:31:40: warning: variable ‘verificacion’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int fila1, fila2, columna1, columna2, verificacion, i, j = 0;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘realizar_operacion_arreglos’:
main.c:167:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  for (size_t i = 0; i < fila1; ++i) {
                       ^
main.c: In function ‘pedir_valores_arreglo1’:
main.c:107:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
main.c: In function ‘pedir_valores_arreglo2’:
main.c:148:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
```

To get rid of these warnings:

1. In the main function, you should have `if (verificacion)` instead of `if (columna1 == fila2)`
2. Variables describing numbers of rows/columns should be of type `size_t` instead of `int`. It's because `int` can't hold all acceptable values, while `size_t` is "crafted" for indexing and similar things. If you want to do this change, you should change all variables like `fila1`, `columna1`, ... to `size_t` type. But I recommend to leave this change to later (if ever), at least if you are OK with having this warning for a few moments.
3. Function `pedir_valores_arreglo1` does not return anything, change it's return value from `void**` to `void`.
4. Do the same with `pedir_valores_arreglo2`.

Your `main()` function also **does not return anything** if the `verificacion` is 1... Which in practise means, that it returns 0 (at least on my computer). But in the text at the beginning of your code, there is specified that in the case of success, the program should return 1. Therefore, add `return 1;` statement right after the last `printf()` call in the main() function.

Comment: In main I edit the variable `m` and  initialized for the array return for the function `realizar_operacion_arreglos(...)` but the cycle still fails..

Comment: @GIOVANNYALEXANDERRODRIGUEZC I have updated my answer.

Comment: I already did but it gives this error when compiling `exited with non-zero status`. I don't have idea why.. I use cycle 
to check if the arrays are correct and check the variables in cycle for multiplication. Also I edit again to check the changes

Comment: @GIOVANNYALEXANDERRODRIGUEZC Sorry, there was a bug in my snippet. I fixed it (there was `++fila1` instead of `++i`). Now the program works correctly for me, please try it.

Comment: I already did but it gives this error when compiling is the same `exited with non-zero status`. I add other form for check if it's possible. Thanks for your help really.

Comment: I tried the result form [fila1] [columna2] and working but say the same in screen `exited with non-zero status`

Comment: @GIOVANNYALEXANDERRODRIGUEZC So, it fails during compilation, or during execution? If it compiles but fails when running, it might be the problem that your program does not return 1 when the multiplication could be done. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @GIOVANNYALEXANDERRODRIGUEZC BTW your last change (`int** resultado[fila1][columna2];`) cannot work, because you cannot return local array from a function (it stops existing the moment the function returns) and you would get right at the beginning, where we faced and equivalent issue

Comment: ya funciono ! i uploaded the changes thanks for your big help.